# Unable to grab value based on MonthNumber and YearNumber SSRS 2010

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I need to grab the value in a column `T` for Particular for `YearNumber = 2018`

and for `MonthNumber = Month(Today())`

Currently its the only value that is `NOT 0`

So I wrote expression for that cell:

```
=IIF((Fields!YearNumber.Value = 2018 AND Fields!MonthNumber.Value = Month(Today()),Fields!T.Value,0)
```

But for some reason it brings me 0.

This is how this number generated in T-sql:

```
ISNULL(case when MonthVal <= MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN  SUM(T) ELSE 0 END /2019317,0) as T,
```

It works if I do the SUM. But I do not need a SUM.

How can I just grab the value of `0.1023` ?

My data looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it number format? if it doesn't or if decimal seperator is wrong, It may lead to wrong result

Comment: You can try cstr(year) =‘2018’ and cstr(month) = csrt(month(today())

Comment: Thanks. But still, no effect.

Comment: Can you show the data types for the relevant columns in your source data?

Comment: Jeff, I am not sure how to get datatypes from a stored procedure. But what datatype should be in order to get desirable result?

Comment: The fact that SUM works seems to indicate that you have another row in your data for 2018 - 01 with 0 T.

Answer (score 0):

In your second picture it looks like you grouped your data by `Commercial Auto` but your expression picks just one row from the dataset. This could be the first row where the condition is true, thus the value could be zero. I think what you need to put in your expression is something like this:

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!YearNumber.Value = 2018 AND 
          Fields!MonthNumber.Value = Month(Today()),
          Fields!T.Value,
          0), 
      "YourCommercialAutoGroupName")
```